# Publish a WordPress document with Installer.php documents already in my computer

Tags: wordpress

I already have the WordPress.zip document with Installer.php documents already in my computer. I want to use a hosting, to create a website. I already tried using 000webhost.com and digitalocean.com (they are so hard to use) how can I upload them to create a website. (I have never used Wordpress before, thats why I can´t upload it that easy) Please!

Comment: Question is not clear. I assume you have your Wordpress website developed and ready. And you need help regarding how to host this website on a hosting service. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear ...but so far i understood i can give a solution.

Step 1 : If you want to upload full wordpress project from your local host ,pleae make a zip file for folders and export database aswell.
Step 2: In you domain public folder you can upload your zip file and extract it.
Step 3: Create a database and there phpmyadmin area you can import your localhost database.

You will get more information here https://blog.templatetoaster.com/move-wordpress-localhost-to-live-server/